# Why did the DC-3 have wing sweep?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, aviation-history, wing-sweep, dc-3

When looking at the silhouette of a DC-3, one can clearly see that the wings are swept. This design is from 1935, before the high-speed research work on wing sweep was ever implemented, and the DC-3 was not very fast anyhow.

Leading edge sweep was 14 deg and trailing edge 0 deg, so the quarter chord wing sweep was 10.5 deg, not inconsiderable, and causing some of the ugly [stall behaviour](http://www.pprune.org/tech-log/89061-dc3-stall-characteristics.html) associated with wing sweep. A 1938 NACA [video of a DC-3 stalling here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SlQZJcAoERg), a bit lengthy but it illustrates the tip stalling first, then the aileron.

None of the benefits and some of the drawbacks - why did the DC-3 have wing sweep?

[image][Image Source](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gec-discussions/5daDPb0A9LA)

Comment: Notice how the trailing edge is at a right angle to the fuselage, which simplifies the aileron design. My first instinct says the design was settled on a tapered wing and they had to choose which wing edge would be at a right angle to the fuselage, and went with the trailing one. Overall that amount of sweep is neglegible.

Comment: Many other aircraft had tapered wings at the time. The DC-3 had 14 deg leading edge, 0 deg trailing, resulting in 10.5 deg at quarter chord line. The [Fokker 100](https://www.the-blueprints.com/vectordrawings/show/4603/fokker_100/) has 15 deg at quarter chord, flies at Mach 0.77.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The wing was swept to move the center of lift back, closer to the center of gravity. When the design of the [DC-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_DC-1) was advanced to a point where the center of gravity became clear, a redesign of the wing-fuselage intersection would had been more effort, so the outer wing panels were swept back a little.

From [this website](https://www.princeton.edu/~hos/mike/texts/readmach/lucker.htm) by [Jeff Lucker](http://www.towntopics.com/wordpress/2016/06/01/profiles-in-education-jeff-lucker/):

> the unique and characteristic swept wing of the DC-3 was an attempt to
>   keep the wing in its original location as the center of gravity moved
>   toward the rear.

When Douglas produced new variants (DC-2 and DC-2 sleeper, a.k.a. DC-3), they kept the proven layout.

Comment: Why did they do that, instead of putting a plug in front of the wing, I wonder.

Comment: @Koyovis: At those times the fuselage was aerodynamically shaped and not meant to be extended. Every bulkhead was different (a tradition which became a liability for the Constellation later). Only with pressurization and the rationalization in production during the war did the preference shift to cylindrical fuselages.